# How to return custom value from function call?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I am trying to call a function called `account.user_available_sel` in PostgreSQL 13 which returns a table of data. It is very simple like this:

```
SELECT * FROM account.user_available_sel(_email => 'email@xxx.xxx');
```

The `SELECT *` part returns back the entire table of data which includes the user's `email, password, forename, surname. dob` etc.

Because this is only supposed to check if an `email` has not already been registered, I only want to return a simple value like `invalid` if a record exists. In my mind something like this (obviously does not work):

```
SELECT 'invalid' FROM account.user_available_sel(_email => 'email@xxx.xxx');
```

How could I just return that string instead of the entire recordset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to get a Boolean.

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM account.user_available_sel(_email => 'email@xxx.xxx'));
```

And if that isn't satisfying, you can of course slap a `CASE` around it and get self defined strings.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM account.user_available_sel(_email => 'email@xxx.xxx')) THEN
           'existent'
         ELSE
           'non-existent'
       END;
```

Similarly you can do that for numbers or whatever you like.